# Pandas warning 'rows is deprecated, use index instead'

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, kaggle

I'm working with the Kaggle Titanic dataset using pandas in an iPython notebook.

When I create a pivot table, I get the following warning:

> FutureWarning: rows is deprecated, use index instead
>   warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)

Is this something I should be concerned about? What I did was just create a pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5743203/data/titanic/titanic_train.csv')
fare_means = df.pivot_table('Fare', rows='Pclass', aggfunc='mean')
```

In addition, when I try to use the values in the pivot table to fill in NA values, I get the following warning:

> FutureWarning: scalar indexers for index type Int64Index should be integers and not floating point
>     type(self).**name**),FutureWarning

```
df['Fare'] = df[['Fare', 'Pclass']].apply(lambda x:
                fare_means[x['Pclass']] if pd.isnull(x['Fare'])
                else x['Fare'], axis=1)
```

Comment: The second warning is warning you about the potential problem of trying to use a float as an index which could cause issues due to equality comparison, the first one is presumably a param clarification to prefer `index` over `rows`

Comment: As Ed said, pivot_table wants to be more explicit about the row pivot in the future since it sets the row as the index for the pivot result.  So change your code to: `fare_means = df.pivot_table('Fare', index='Pclass', aggfunc='mean')` to be future proof =)

Answer (score 1):

From [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) in Pandas 1.2.4. the `rows` is not a parameter.

Therefore, changing `rows` to `index` should solve your problem

```
fare_means = df.pivot_table('Fare', index='Pclass', aggfunc='mean')
```